# How can I use findViewById within a static method?

Tags: java, android, static, findviewbyid

I would like to use findViewById in my method `setTotalSum` which is called from another class.
How can I use it although it's a static method?

```
public SecondaryDisplay(Context outerContext, Display display) {
    super(outerContext, display);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_display);
}

public static void setTotalSum (String invoiceTotalSum){
    TextView totalPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.invoicePrice);
    totalPrice.setText(invoiceTotalSum);
}
```

Comment: is another class is an Activity or Fragment? and i will suggest you don't do like this as this is a bad practice and there are chances that you will leak your context if not released within the method.

Comment: You don't have to do this do not reference View inside a static code block it can cause problem when view is destroyed.  Also i see you have a parameterized constructor Is that right ? if yes u should not have constructor inside Activity .

Comment: and how can I set the view with my data if I should not do it like that? pls help

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById()` is an instance method of the `View` which is the parent of `Activity` and `Fragment`. You can't use instance methods in static methods.

Either you should pass the view as the param (what I would not recommend) or find another way around to do it without static methods.

```
public static void setTotalSum (View view, String invoiceTotalSum){
    TextView totalPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invoicePrice);
    totalPrice.setText(invoiceTotalSum);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- If two class is in same package then directly call another class static method by class name.

### A.java

```
public class A {
    public static some() {
      ...
    }
}
```

### B.java

```
public class B {
    public static someExtra() {
      A.some(); //call by class name
      
      A a = new A();
      a.some(); //call by refrence also
    }
}
```

but if some is not static method then create object of A class and then call the method.

### Ex:-

```
public class B {
    public static someExtra() {
        A a = new A();
        a.some();
    }
}
```

**Note:-** If two class is in diffrent package then must include import.